# Vagrant Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot

Tags: ssh, timeout, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am new Vagrant. My current environment is Ubuntu -> running on Virtual Box -> on a Mac book.

I have successfully installed the Virtualbox and Vagrant packages on my Ubuntu install. I set my repo and started my build (vagrant up). After image is successfully copied I have step in my vagrantfile to connect via SSH to the VM.. It just hangs and ultimately times out.

See error below

```
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/trusty64
==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20190514.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20190514.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: postgres_default_1588691813886_34109
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...

Vagrant is currently configured to create VirtualBox synced folders with
the `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` option enabled. If the Vagrant
guest is not trusted, you may want to disable this option. For more
information on this option, please refer to the VirtualBox manual:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

This option can be disabled globally with an environment variable:

  VAGRANT_DISABLE_VBOXSYMLINKCREATE=1

or on a per folder basis within the Vagrantfile:

  config.vm.synced_folder '/host/path', '/guest/path', SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key

#<Thread:0x00005618d3a47468@/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-2.0.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:71 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):

....
....
....

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that (Vagrant::Errors::VMBootTimeout)

Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

Vagrantfile

# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# # vi: set ft=ruby :

IMAGE_NAME = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
N = 1

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = IMAGE_NAME
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/vagrant_provision.sh", privileged: true

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 2048 
    v.cpus = 1
  end

  # Nodes
  (1..N).each do |number|
      config.vm.define "node-#{number}" do |node|
          node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.21#{number}"
          node.vm.hostname = "node-#{number}"
          node.vm.synced_folder "scripts/", "/scripts"
      end  
  end


end
```

Comment: Can you provide your `Vagrantfile`

Comment: I can't read that...  edit your answer to include your `Vagrantfile` and delete theses comments.

Comment: I added it the Vagrantfile up top as well to my post..

Comment: Why is there `....` instead of the error stacktrace ? It seems the log and the `Vagrantfile` doesn't match. In the log it says `ubuntu/trusty64` and in the vagrant file it says `bento/ubuntu-18.04`.

Comment: I tried both sources which work.. The issue is when I try to SSH to the VM where it hangs.. In effort to remediate the issue through other posts. I have gotten multiple errors in regards to SSH.

Comment: An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses. (Vagrant::Errors::NetSSHException)
The error message is shown below. In many cases, errors from this
library are caused by ssh-agent issues. Try disabling your SSH
agent or removing some keys and try again.
If the problem persists, please report a bug to the net-ssh project.
timeout during server version negotiating
An error occurred in the underlying SSH library that Vagrant uses.

Comment: You have to update the question not post things in comment

Comment: Sorry, what do you looking for specifically? The Vagrantfile

Comment: Issue seems to be related tou sing Vagrant/VirtualBox under an Ubuntu VM that was already running VirtualBox on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to using Vagrant/VirtualBox under an Ubuntu VM that was already running VirtualBox on a Mac. When I installed Vagrant/VirtualBox on the Mac natively I had no issues.